# Identify email id configured in email app in ios device

Tags: ios

i have requirement where in my app i can send some data as attachment via email to people in my contact. when the user opens attachment, it opens with the help of my app and saves the data in the receiver's app's database. also actions assigned to that person gets saved in his device's calendar as an event. the problem is that i will be sending the data to multiple recipients and action tasks assigned to everyone, so i need to know the receiving person's identity to save only task assigned to him in his device's calendar as event. now the requirement given to me is when creating action task for each person i also need to save his email-id[as person is selected from contacts stored in that device], so if i can find the receiver's email id i can identify tasks assigned to only him and save to his calendar.

Comment: I believe you'll need to use a backend to store the users data as even if it was possible to read the Mail configuration, normally the user could change it anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As This is not possible to get Configured Email details in iOS Device (in Non Jailbroken device, no idea with Jail broken device) it breaks user privacy.